# NestJS JwtModule - Purpose of using verify and public key

Tags: authentication, jwt, passport.js, nestjs

The nest documentation for verifying a valid jwt suggests using the @nestjs/passport package and PassportStrategy with the passport-jwt strategy. Then, it suggests using @nest/jwt and the JwtModule to sign the tokens. However, the JwtModule also provides a verify function to verify that the token is valid. Why does the documentation show that passport-jwt should be used for verification instead of the nestjs/jwt package?

Authentication documentation found here [NestJS Authentication](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication)

NestJS JwtModule documentation found here [NestJS nestjs/jwt](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt)

Answer (score 2):

The `JwtModule` is just a wrapper around `jsonwebtoken` and it's methods, for the most part, to allow them to fit better into the architecture of NestJS. If you decide to use `passport` and an authentication library, then you'll want to use the `passport` related methods (like the `JwtStrategy`) to keep most of your code in line with itself and if you choose to switch out to another passport strategy, it will help mitigate the changes necessary.

If you decide to not to use `passport` then you can absolutely use the `JwtModule`and the `JwtService`'s `verify` function to check for the validity of the token.

Overall, the `JwtModule` has the capability to handle authentication on it's own, but if you are using the passport library already, you may as well go ahead and use `passport-jwt` for authentication

Comment: could you please also give a specific example when to use verify and when verifyAsync?

Comment: Use `verify` when you have a synchronous secret. Use `verifyAsync` when you have an asynchronous secret. [You can view the implementation for how that works](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt/blob/master/lib/jwt.service.ts#L109)

Comment: thank you for your reply. Regarding the next statement: ` const decodedToken = await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(refreshToken, {
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      });` should i use verify  or verifyAsync? My opinion is `verify`. But when secret could be async?